Why aren't camera access rights saved? [Telegram Mini Apps]
I am writing a small app and I need to access the camera. In the desktop version, the user's choice is remembered, but not in the mobile version. Every time the app is opened, access is requested, which is a bit annoying. How can this be fixed? I couldn't find anything about the camera in the documentation.
const myVideoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
 useEffect(() => {
    const initCamera = async () => {
      try {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then((currentStream) =>{
          if (myVideoRef.current) {
            myVideoRef.current.srcObject = currentStream;
          }
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Camera access error:", err);
      }
    };
    initCamera();
   }, []);
   ...
   <video ref={myVideoRef} autoPlay muted playsInline />


Have you tried on different phones/OS? Maybe you need to mention it somewhere in the Manifest?

@stefan-hegny, I've only tried on Android. Editing the Manifest didn't work.

and what is the "desktop version" that you mention?

@stefan-hegny, desktop version of Telegram. As I understand it, the methods of displaying web applications in the mobile and desktop versions of Telegram are different.

Hey, I have the same issue with the microphone permission. I'm using a flutter webapp but on Android the permissions are non-persistants. Did you find any solution yet?

@elios_cama, no, I haven't found a solution yet.
